# how use same layout in two areas mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I have the following project structure:

```
Layout = "~/Areas/BaseAdmin1/Views/Shared/_LayoutP.cshtml";

~/Areas/BaseAdmin1/Views/ControllerName/Index;
...
~/Areas/BaseAdmin2/Views/ControllerName/Index;
```

Is there any way to force all areas to use the `_Layout` as a base layout?

I am use in view on BaseAdmin2

```
Layout = "~/Areas/BaseAdmin1/Views/Shared/_LayoutP.cshtml";
```

but when run view from baseadmin2 see error Page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are straight file references; they're not bound to any particular area. Simply create `Areas\[Area Name]\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml` and inside add the following code:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/BaseAdmin1/Views/Shared/_LayoutP.cshtml";
}
```

Then, that layout will be used for all views within the area you placed this file in.

If you're getting a 404 error, that has nothing to do with your layout. There's something wrong with the URL you're using to access the page.

Comment: iam use _LayoutP in baseadmin1 view i want use layoutP in baseadmin2